# jQuery buttons toggle is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create an accordion menu for my project. Mostly done, but I have an issue with open-close buttons. I need the buttons to change state when I click the next tab. But they are not changing. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('.answers__tabTitle').next().hide();
 $('.answers__tabTitle').click(function(){
 $(this).next().slideToggle();
 $('.answers__tabTitle').not(this).next().stop(true,true).slideUp();
 $(this).addClass('active');
 $('.active .open-close').toggleClass('on');
 $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.answers__tabText {
 font-family: "MuseoSansCyrl_300";
 font-size: 21px;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 20px;
}

.answers__tabTitle .open-close {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 float: right;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 transition: all .3s ease;
 opacity: .8;
}

.answers__tabTitle .on {
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answers__tabsWrap">

     <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит установка входной двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Установка входной двери зависит от многих факторов. Минимальная цена, которая может быть это 1 600 рублей. Точную цену установки, под Ваш проём может назвать технический специалист на замере.</p> 
      <hr>
     </div>

     <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько времени идёт изготовление двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Процесс изготовления стандартных дверей занимает 7-10 дней, а нестандартных 10-14 дней в зависимости от сложности конструкции двери. Возможно срочное изготовление за 3 дня. Доплата 1 000 рублей.</p> 
      <hr>
     </div>

     <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит замер проёма входной двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Замер проёма входной двери по Ульяновской области бесплатный.</p> 
      <hr>
     </div>

     <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит демонтаж старой двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Демонтаж старой двери бесплатный.</p> 
      <hr>
     </div>

     <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Когда будет установка входной двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Установка стандартных дверей, которые есть на складе может быть произведена на следующий день после заключения договора. Если Вам нужна дверь нестандартного размера, то надо будет ожидать время изготовления, потом Вам позвонит менеджер и Вы с ним договоритесь на любой удобный для вас день.</p> 
      <hr>
     </div>

     <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит доставка входной двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Доставка входной двери в пределах города Ульяновска стоит 500 рублей, а за пределами города 1 километр = 17 рублей. Также возможен самовывоз входной двери.</p> 
      <hr>
     </div>

    </div>
```

$('.answers__tabTitle').not(this).removeClass('active');

This fix partially solves the problem BUT sometimes the buttons stay pressed when switching them in random order. How can I fix this?
[screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h26O1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution was found!
Added this code to the end of the script:

```
$('.open-close').not('.active .open-close').removeClass('on');
```

And this works! Thanks to all (and me, of course;)) for help!

```js
 $('.answers__tabTitle').next().hide();
 $('.answers__tabTitle').click(function(){
     $(this).next().slideToggle();
     $('.answers__tabTitle').not(this).next().stop(true,true).slideUp();
     $(this).addClass('active');
     $('.active .open-close').toggleClass('on');
     $('.answers__tabTitle').not(this).removeClass('active');
     $('.open-close').not('.active .open-close').removeClass('on');
});
```

```css
.answers__tabText {
     font-family: "MuseoSansCyrl_300";
     font-size: 21px;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 20px;
    }

    .answers__tabTitle .open-close {
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     float: right;
     transition: all .3s ease;
     opacity: .4;
    }

    .answers__tabTitle .on {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
     opacity: .8;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answers__tabsWrap">
   <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит установка входной двери?<img class="open-close" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Установка входной двери зависит от многих факторов. Минимальная цена, которая может быть это 1 600 рублей. Точную цену установки, под Ваш проём может назвать технический специалист на замере.</p>
      <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько времени идёт изготовление двери?<img class="open-close" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Процесс изготовления стандартных дверей занимает 7-10 дней, а нестандартных 10-14 дней в зависимости от сложности конструкции двери. Возможно срочное изготовление за 3 дня. Доплата 1 000 рублей.</p>
      <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит замер проёма входной двери?<img class="open-close" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Замер проёма входной двери по Ульяновской области бесплатный.</p>
      <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит демонтаж старой двери?<img class="open-close" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Демонтаж старой двери бесплатный.</p>
      <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Когда будет установка входной двери?<img class="open-close" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Установка стандартных дверей, которые есть на складе может быть произведена на следующий день после заключения договора. Если Вам нужна дверь нестандартного размера, то надо будет ожидать время изготовления, потом Вам позвонит менеджер и Вы с ним договоритесь на любой удобный для вас день.</p>
      <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит доставка входной двери?<img class="open-close" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Доставка входной двери в пределах города Ульяновска стоит 500 рублей, а за пределами города 1 километр = 17 рублей. Также возможен самовывоз входной двери.</p>
      <hr>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the last line to:

```
$('.answers__tabTitle').not(this).removeClass('active');
```

heres a working example:

```js
 $('.answers__tabTitle').next().hide();
 $('.answers__tabTitle').click(function(){
     $(this).next().slideToggle();
     $('.answers__tabTitle').not(this).next().stop(true,true).slideUp();
     $(this).addClass('active');
     $('.active .open-close').toggleClass('on');
     $('.answers__tabTitle').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.answers__tabText {
     font-family: "MuseoSansCyrl_300";
     font-size: 21px;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 20px;
    }

    .answers__tabTitle .open-close {
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     float: right;
     transform: rotate(45deg);
     transition: all .3s ease;
     opacity: .8;
    }

    .answers__tabTitle .on {
     transform: rotate(0deg);
     opacity: .4;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answers__tabsWrap">
   <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит установка входной двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Установка входной двери зависит от многих факторов. Минимальная цена, которая может быть это 1 600 рублей. Точную цену установки, под Ваш проём может назвать технический специалист на замере.</p>
      <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько времени идёт изготовление двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Процесс изготовления стандартных дверей занимает 7-10 дней, а нестандартных 10-14 дней в зависимости от сложности конструкции двери. Возможно срочное изготовление за 3 дня. Доплата 1 000 рублей.</p>
      <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит замер проёма входной двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Замер проёма входной двери по Ульяновской области бесплатный.</p>
      <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит демонтаж старой двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Демонтаж старой двери бесплатный.</p>
      <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Когда будет установка входной двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Установка стандартных дверей, которые есть на складе может быть произведена на следующий день после заключения договора. Если Вам нужна дверь нестандартного размера, то надо будет ожидать время изготовления, потом Вам позвонит менеджер и Вы с ним договоритесь на любой удобный для вас день.</p>
      <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="answers__tab">
      <hr>
      <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит доставка входной двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
      <p class="answers__tabText">Доставка входной двери в пределах города Ульяновска стоит 500 рублей, а за пределами города 1 километр = 17 рублей. Также возможен самовывоз входной двери.</p>
      <hr>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've found a new problem. Sometimes the buttons stay pressed when switching them in random order. How can I fix this?   http://i.piccy.info/i9/2e6363b92c130d45999b0baca3e6e415/1528867147/8393/1250964/Bezymiannyi.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Yow almost got it. See my snippet below. It was only a matter of changing the last line for this:

```
$('.answers__tabTitle').not(this).removeClass('active');
```

```js
$('.answers__tabTitle').next().hide();
$('.answers__tabTitle').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
  $('.answers__tabTitle').not(this).next().stop(true, true).slideUp();
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.active .open-close').toggleClass('on');
  $('.answers__tabTitle').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.answers__tabText {
  font-family: "MuseoSansCyrl_300";
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

.answers__tabTitle .open-close {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  opacity: .8;
}

.answers__tabTitle .on {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answers__tabsWrap">

  <div class="answers__tab">
    <hr>
    <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит установка входной двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
    <p class="answers__tabText">Установка входной двери зависит от многих факторов. Минимальная цена, которая может быть это 1 600 рублей. Точную цену установки, под Ваш проём может назвать технический специалист на замере.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

  <div class="answers__tab">
    <hr>
    <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько времени идёт изготовление двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
    <p class="answers__tabText">Процесс изготовления стандартных дверей занимает 7-10 дней, а нестандартных 10-14 дней в зависимости от сложности конструкции двери. Возможно срочное изготовление за 3 дня. Доплата 1 000 рублей.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

  <div class="answers__tab">
    <hr>
    <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит замер проёма входной двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
    <p class="answers__tabText">Замер проёма входной двери по Ульяновской области бесплатный.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

  <div class="answers__tab">
    <hr>
    <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит демонтаж старой двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
    <p class="answers__tabText">Демонтаж старой двери бесплатный.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

  <div class="answers__tab">
    <hr>
    <p class="answers__tabTitle">Когда будет установка входной двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
    <p class="answers__tabText">Установка стандартных дверей, которые есть на складе может быть произведена на следующий день после заключения договора. Если Вам нужна дверь нестандартного размера, то надо будет ожидать время изготовления, потом Вам позвонит менеджер и Вы с ним
      договоритесь на любой удобный для вас день.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

  <div class="answers__tab">
    <hr>
    <p class="answers__tabTitle">Сколько стоит доставка входной двери?<img class="open-close on" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/ee9f224ec07247dfc032542552a70df2/1528841272/408/1250964/open_close.png" alt="open-close"></p>
    <p class="answers__tabText">Доставка входной двери в пределах города Ульяновска стоит 500 рублей, а за пределами города 1 километр = 17 рублей. Также возможен самовывоз входной двери.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

</div>
```